# Error: Invalid use of non-static data member, variable was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, inner-classes

The following is an internal nested class within a templated class for a skiplist. I get the error: "height was not declared in this scope" at the line declaring *next.

```
        class Node{
            public:
                Node(int height){
                    this->height = height;
                }
                Node(Key_t key, Mapped_t obj, int height){
                    value = std::make_pair(key, obj);
                    this->height = height;
                }
                SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node *next[height];
                int getHeight(){return height;}
                Key_t getKey(){return value.first;}
                Mapped_t getObj(){return value.second;}
            private:
                std::pair<Key_t, Mapped_t> value;
                int height;
        };
```

Moving the declaration of value and height before everything else, as follows, changes the error to "invalid use of non-static data member.

```
         class Node{
                private:
                    std::pair<Key_t, Mapped_t> value;
                    int height;
                public:
                    Node(int height){
                        this->height = height;
                    }
                    Node(Key_t key, Mapped_t obj, int height){
                        value = std::make_pair(key, obj);
                        this->height = height;
                    }
                    SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node *next[height];
                    int getHeight(){return height;}
                    Key_t getKey(){return value.first;}
                    Mapped_t getObj(){return value.second;}
            };
```

I'm at a loss as for what to do to solve this. Here is the entire class:

```
template <class Key_t, class Mapped_t>
class SkipList{
public:
    SkipList(int prob, int max){
        probOutOf100 = prob;
        maxHeight = max;
        head = new SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node(maxHeight);
        tail = new SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node(maxHeight);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxHeight; i++){
            head->next[i] = tail;
        }
    }
    ~SkipList(){
        delete head;
        delete tail;
    }

    class Node{
        public:
            Node(int height){
                this->height = height;
            }
            Node(Key_t key, Mapped_t obj, int height){
                value = std::make_pair(key, obj);
                this->height = height;
            }
            SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node *next[height];
            int getHeight(){return height;}
            Key_t getKey(){return value.first;}
            Mapped_t getObj(){return value.second;}
        private:
            std::pair<Key_t, Mapped_t> value;
            int height;
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int probOutOf100;
    int maxHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1

You can't use what the compiler hasn't seen yet, so moving the declaration above the usage solves this problem. You've done this already. Good job.

## Problem 2

`height` will not be known until the object is constructed. You can't construct the object if the size of the object is not known, and `height` determines the size of `next` which contributes to the size of the object. Catch 22.

Recommend using a `std::vector` in place of the array and initializing the vector with `height` in the constructors's [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)s. Example:

```
std::vector<SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node *> next;

Node(int height): height(height), next(height)
{
}
Node(Key_t key, Mapped_t obj, int height): 
    value(std::make_pair(key, obj)),
    height(height), 
    next(height)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line below

```
SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node *next[height];
```

you are attempting to declare an array of pointers. However, you cannot do that unless `height` is known at compile time.

You may want to change it to a `vector` and initialize it at run time.

```
std::vector<SkipList<Key_t, Mapped_t>::Node*> next;


...

Node(int height) : next(height) {
    this->height = height;
}
```

**PS** I am not sure what data structure uses an array of pointers as the "next" nodes of a node. Just something to think about.